# Creating a file in php

Tags: php, file

I am trying to create a file in php and after the file run they get error(failed to open stream).and my php code is:-

```
<?php
  $fileLocation = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/myfile.txt";
  $file = fopen($fileLocation,"w");
  $content = "Your text here";
  fwrite($file,$content);
  fclose($file);
?>
```

how can i fix the error.

Comment: You should check if you have permission to write to the document root. Usually you create files in a logs folder or gallery folder and not directly into the document root. if(is_writeable(getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT')) fopen($fileLocation, 'w'); else die('Permission denied');

Comment: add these lines to you php file `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` to find out what is the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a permission error.

You don't have right to create file at the location you are trying to create, it means the user from which you are logged in doesn't have that right.

Try **chmod 777 /path/to/file** if you are using Unix like Operating Sytem also try **changing the User**.

Answer (score 3):

There is a permision error. Assuming you're using ubuntu (from profile), check chmod 777. The webserver uses your account to create files.

Answer (score 0):

Print out fileLocation and check if it has the value you are expecting.
Also fopen, can't create folders so make sure that the folder exists and is writeable by the apache process.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have the permission on the folder to create a file! so try this:

Otherwise check the permission on the folder (chmod) and if required an possible change it!

```
<?php
    $fileLocation = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . getenv("REQUEST_URI") ."myfile.txt";
    $file = fopen($fileLocation, "w");
    $content = "Your text here";
    fwrite($file,$content);
    fclose($file);
?>
```